# docker run python script in CMD with environment variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a simple Dockerfile that runs a python script and takes some environment variable as an argument (using argparser):

```
FROM python:2.7
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install argparse
ENV POOL "pool_argument"
CMD ["python", "script.py", "--pool", "${POOL}"]
```

and my python script `script.py`:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--pool', required=True)
known_args, unknown_args = parser.parse_known_args()
print("Args: {}".format(known_args))
```

after building and running, I'm getting:

```
Args: Namespace(pool='${POOL}')
```

I tried many variations of this, but none seemed to work.

Comment: side note: python2.7 is deprecated, I'd recommend you transition to python3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to run with `sh -c` to evaluate the environment variables:

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "python script.py --pool ${POOL}"]
```